# GitHub is pushing my commit as author as well as non author. What should I do?

Tags: github, git-commit

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXnMM.png)

Also, instead of using my username commit is being made by my name.

I checked my username for conflicts and there weren't any.

> git status config --list

Comment: If you're connected with a different account than the one you're committing with, it will do something like that. You didn't include any commit information so we can't tell

Comment: @Axnyff git log?

Comment: git show of that commit will show what is the author. You could also try to hover over your name, there will probably be something like non-author committer

Comment: git show commit shows correct name and username. And yes, it shows non-author committer

Comment: @Axnyff See this https://imgur.com/a/1SP4v